# Does synchronous programming on an Express server block other visitors from loading the page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I'm writing a simple (one page) web app that relies on loading weather data from a file (I have a separate script to refresh the data periodically so I don't have to perform a ton of HTTP requests for each visitor).

I'm using `fs.readFileSync()` because none of the code works until the data has been loaded as a Javascript object. So I figured that I need synchronous programming in this specific instance.

I'm new to node.js and asynchronous programming, and I have a question: hypothetically, suppose that `fs.readFileSync` takes 3 seconds to load the file, and everything else executes instantly. If Visitor A visits the site, it would take 3 seconds for the page to load. At t=1 second, if I receive a new Visitor B, does Visitor B have to wait 3 seconds or 5 seconds?

Does the synchronous code block subsequent code from executing only for the current visitor, or does it prevent Express from serving any other visitors?

Update: after receiving responses telling me what a bad idea synchronous operations are on an Express webserver, I've changed the code from:

```
var locationList = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('locationList.json'));

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
        locationList: locationList
    });
});
```

To:

```
var locationList;
fs.readFile('locationList.json', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    locationList = JSON.parse(data);
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
        locationList: locationList
    });
});
```

Just wondering if this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Actually your first snippet isn't that bad. Notice that it does read the file in the 3 seconds *before* opening the server and serving any clients - which happens immediately for each then. Notice that it does not read in the file again for each request it is getting. Of course, that also means the responses won't change when the file is periodically updated, at least not until you restart the server.

Comment: I would even argue that the second script is far worse. Instead of not serving any requests in the first 3 seconds, it does serve them but with the wrong data.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use synchronous functions for io, the only function that should be synchronous is `require` which node uses to pull in dependent files, everything else should be asynchronous, and with `async` functions you can still keep the same control flow in you program to make it **"look"** synchronous.

You could use `util.promisify` to convert the function to a promise, then use an `async` function to wait for the promise to resolve.

```
import { readFile } from 'fs'
import { promisify } from 'util'

const readFilePromise = promisify(readFile)

async function app() {
  try {
    const file = await readFilePromise('filename.txt')
    console.log('file:', file)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('error:', e)
  }
}

app()
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will "block" the server. So you should avoid using synchronous functions frequently. You can also use a load balancer or a cluster to improve the performance distributing the load across multiple instances.

[Express Performance Guide](http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html)

Comment: You shouldn't avoid using synchronous functions altogether, that's an overstatement - just make sure that potentially *long-running*  operations are async - in the OP's case it's an IO operation which are inherently slow thus a perfect candidate for doing it async.

Comment: @Nicholas yes, i didn't mean he cant never use sync functions , just that is not recommended. Sometimes using a sync function is needed

Comment: I generally agree but I'd change the wording. It's not recommended on I/O or network operations - everything else just do it synchronously.

Comment: Would this be the correct implementation then? 

`var locationList;
fs.readFile('locationList.json', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    locationList = JSON.parse(data);
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
        locationList: locationList
    });
});`

Comment: In this case its okay to use it. If you use sync, it will only block the thread at the server start. If you use async, the server will start faster but you won't be able to know if the function finished.